# stop a long running PS cmdlet

Tags: powershell

I've seen articles that mention hitting Ctrl+C or Ctrl+Break to stop Powershell in it's tracks but I see varied responses to this.
For example if I run:
   `dir -include *.txt -recurse` 
And then get tired of watching screens of info I will try to break out using one of the keyboard shortcuts mentioned above but it keeps on going. Alt + F4 is the only thing that works.
What is the best way to kill it instantly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `Ctrl+C` or `CTRL + Break` should stop any command.

For more info about breaking running scripts/commands

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/powershell/2014/11/19/powershell-break-all-command/

Comment: Not for me. If you run the same cmd at the c:\ do either of those keyboard combos halt execution for you?

Comment: Why in the world would you `dir -recurse` at the root of a volume with no output suppression or assignment?!

Comment: Some commands take a little while to respond because they aren't checking for a break every millisecond. Usually they finish the current task, or section of the task, before returning.